# Why am I getting a "cache not found in 'react'" error when trying to import cache from React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm following a doc from [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/guides/ssr#using-hydrate) that includes a section about using the Hydrate component in Next.js 13 app directory with server-side rendering. In this section, the guide imports the cache object from React like this:

```
import { cache } from 'react';
```

However, when I try to import cache from React in my own project, I get an error that says "cache not found in 'react'".

Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it? Do I need to install a separate package to use the cache object in React?

Comment: I never heard about this function in `react` and I can't find it in the docs either. I assume this is an error in the example you're following.

Comment: I'm facing this issue while using monorepo with turborepo

Answer (score 4):

The `cache` object is not imported from React itself, but rather from the `next` package in the context of Next.js applications.

To correctly import the cache object, you should first ensure that your dependencies are properly set up in your package.json file.

Here is mine:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^18.0.2",
  "next": "^13.1.1"
}
```

NPM installation:

```
npm i next@13.1.1
```

YARN installation:

```
yarn add next@13.1.1
```

Since the cache object is part of the next package, you can find its type definition in the following path: `node_modules/next/types/index.d.ts`.

The react-query documentation starts with the [Using Next.js](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/guides/ssr#using-hydrate:%7E:text=setup%20up%20front-,Using%20Next.js,-The%20exact%20implementation) section. Although it may not be explicitly stated, it's important to install Next.js to access the features described in the documentation, such as the cache function. Installing Next.js should help resolve the issue you've encountered.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only use the 'cache' from React in Next, if your page is in the 'app' directory. It won't work if you have it in the 'pages' directory.

Answer (score 0):

Cache cannot be uses with react versions older that 16.8. You should check  the version you're using.

```
npm list react
```

If you're using a compatible version, reinstall react.